# how do I get a string from my http response android?

Tags: android, string, http, httpresponse

I've seen some really ugly looking code from people writing up their own methods of converting an HttpResponse to a string to use later, that looks something like this:

```java
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF8"),8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
String line="0";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
String result = sb.toString();
```

not only is that somewhat of a mess, but it's really ugly and I often times can't tell what's going on with the code because this mess precedes it. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

YES, THERE IS! YOU CAN DO ALL OF THAT IN ONE LINE! Just like this:

```
response = client.execute(post);
String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

happy app making

Comment: There is one problem with this.  If the response is gzipped, this will not work.  You have to call 'InputStream stream = AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent(response.getEntity());' and then convert the InputStream to a string.  I haven't found a better way yet.

Comment: is possible works in 2013, but in 2016 not !  this is my error - > Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception.

Answer (score 4):

I did it with response handler from the [HttpClient.execute documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29). Using handler as a second parameter to the .execute method defines in what format the response should be.
My code is as folows:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = "";
        try {
            response = client.execute(request, handler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`params[0]` is a URL in form of a string. It may be important to say that my server returns responses in JSON. So in the end I convert my `response` string to JSON.

Comment: Works great for me, my promotion code validation servers return plain string "VALID" or "INVALID".