# Why we need to use BufferedReader instead of String while getting the response from server

Tags: java, android, httpclient, bufferedreader

I am doing an android application, Which is getting some JSON values from server. So I made some studies and develop the code for get data from server to my app.

Simply I am using the below code for that.

```
    HttpResponse response;
    Object content = null;
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    response = client.execute(targetHost, httpget,localContext);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);   
    Log.d("content", "OK: " + content.toString());
```

When I looked in to some tutorials, They used [BufferedReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html) for the same operation like this.

```
     HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
     InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
     InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     String bufferedStrChunk = null;
     while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }
     Log.d("content", "OK: " + stringBuilder.toString());
```

So my questions are:

1. Why using the BufferedReader method? Is there any advantage for using this?
2. Till now the first method is working fine for me, is there any chance errors or trouble because of the first method in future?

   Thanks :).

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618792/how-do-i-get-a-string-from-my-http-response-android

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the link dude, But thats not the answer for my question. Any way thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Doing it the way like the answer of that link is just cleaner, just a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why using the BufferedReader method? Is there any advantage for using this?

The `java.io.BufferedReader` class reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.

Buffering can **speed up** IO quite a bit. Rather than read one character at a time from the network or disk, you read a larger block at a time.

> there any chance errors or trouble because of the first method in future?

No, there will not be any error if you do it directly in your code. But it will degrade your performance little bit (maybe in milliseconds) and another thing is, if you don't use `BufferedReader` then size stream coming from server will not be known.

Comment: @RemeesMSyde you could accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: Sure dude I am waiting for more opinions, If yours the best surely I will.

Answer (score 1):

> The `BufferedReader` class provides buffering to your Reader's.
>   Buffering can speed up IO quite a bit. Rather than read one character
>   at a time from the network or disk, you read a larger block at a time.
>   This is typically much faster, especially for disk access and larger
>   data amounts.
>
> The main difference between BufferedReader and BufferedInputStream is
>   that Reader's work on characters (text), wheres InputStream's works on
>   raw bytes.

Great explanation is here: [Java IO: BufferedReader](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/bufferedreader.html)

The `StringBuffer` class is used when there is a necessity to make a lot of modifications to Strings of characters.

Unlike Strings, objects of type `StringBuffer` can be modified over and over again with out leaving behind a lot of new unused objects.

Analogy on this line:

StringBuffer append is as fast as compare to adding of two String object

```
stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk); - //This will fast in cpu execution
String str;
str = str + "some string" // This will slow  in cpu execution
```

Comment: I thik you are confusing BufferedReader with StringBuffer (which usually should be replaced with StringBuilder)

Comment: @Pablo thanks for reminding i have update the answer accordingly.